# How to call random string from an array on Java?

Tags: java

```
String[] prompts = {"Describe to me in a sentence why this is a cool program.", 
                    "Describe to me in a sentence how your day was.", 
                    "Describe to me in a sentence what programming means to you.", 
                    "Describe to me in a sentence why food is neccessary for humans."};
System.out.println(prompts);
```

I want to call a random string from the array how should I report it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to randomly generate an index in the range of your array length

```
int i = new Random().nextInt(prompts.length);
System.out.println(prompts[i]);
```

Comment: @IramShahed please accept if this works :)

Comment: will do in 8 minutes.